# Calculate the area of the hemisphere cut by a plane

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, solid-angle

I have the following problem. There is a unit hemisphere cut by the plane passing through the diameter.

[image: Great circle]

The angle $\gamma$ is given.
The plane cuts a half of the great circle. I need to find the area $S$ of the surface enclosed by the thick black line. Obvioulsy it is sufficient to find the area $S_1$ in one of the quadrants. To do this I define the curve $P_1P_2$ as $\theta=f(\phi)$
and the following integral has to be calculated
$$S_1=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}d\phi\int_{0}^{f(\phi)}\sin\theta d\theta.$$

The problem is I don't know how to find the $f(\phi)$ function. I have tried $$\theta(\phi)=\arctan(\frac{\tan\gamma}{\sin\phi}),$$
but it did not work.

Comment: But that's easy! Imagine $\gamma$ increasing linearly from $0$ to $\pi$; the area of $S$ decreases linearly, from $\frac23\pi$ to $0$.

Comment: @TonyK I need to do it using integrals because ultimately I want to integrate some function $g(\theta)$ on this surface

Comment: While there are mistakes in your work, those can be fixed but the approach you are taking for the integral is very tedious. Simplify your work using projection in xy-plane. See this link for help: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/surfaceintegrals.aspx